# Open a form by id

Tags: php, postgresql

I would like to open a form using a PHP URL by id. The URL looks like this.

```
http://localhost/application/workordersystem/woformEditor.php?woid=4
```

And receiving the id into PostgreSQL like this.

```
if (isset($_GET['woid']))
{
  $query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE woid='$woid'";
  $result = pg_query($query) or die(pg_error());
  $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

I need the forms input fields to be filled with database data by the id in the database. What am I missing?

```
<input type="text" name="status" id="status" value="<?php echo $row['status']; ?>" />
```

Comment: Proper [SQL query parameterization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and [HTML escaping](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), for one...

Comment: No DB Structure! How can we help you? **You are missing the DB structure in the question...**

Comment: What's the problem?  Is this not working?

Comment: [`pg_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php) returns only one row.  You may want to call that in a loop to get all the rows.

Comment: Your right Matt thanks...I left that out

Answer (score 1):

Try debugging like so

```
echo print_r($row);
```

Additionally, you might want to add a limit.  Tell us what you get.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE woid='$woid' LIMIT 1";
```

But you should review the data structure returned by pg_fetch_assoc($result);

You'll want to map the keys you need to the input fields which should be revealed (or anomalies revealed) via the print_r function.